# How to see local uncomitted changes in github

Tags: github, gitk

In our company we are using git.
If I have some file which isn't there and I run command `gitk`, I can see red dot with description:

```
Local uncomitted changes, not checked in to index
```

Now I create new repository in GitHub because I want to work with this tool more efficiently.
But here when I have some file which isn't committed, I can't see any red dot when I run `gitk`.
Is there some option how to set this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can happen, as described in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Local-uncommitted-changes-not-checked-in-to-index-with-gitk-td721528.html), when:

> You are on a case-insensitive file system.
>   The linux kernel source requires a case-sensitive file system because the sources contain both of these files:

```
include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h
include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h
```

Since GitHub is on a case-*sensitive* filesystem, it won't be affected by this issue (hence no "red-dot").